# ViewActions.swipeUp() Doesn't work on Android 12

Tags: android, android-webview, android-espresso, android-testing, android-12

Noticed that one of my espresso android test failing where we perform `ViewActions.swipeUp()` on webview or NestedScrollView. I didn't find any documentation specific to this, would be great if someone can highlight if something got changed in android 12 or so ?

Note - Above does work fine on android 11.